# Mockery & PHPUnit: method does not exist on this mock object

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

Can you tell me where's the problem? I have a file **GeneratorTest.ph**p with the following tests:

```
<?php

namespace stats\Test;

use stats\jway\File;
use stats\jway\Generator;

class GeneratorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function tearDown() {
        \Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testGeneratorFire()
    {
        $fileMock = \Mockery::mock('\stats\jway\File');
        $fileMock->shouldReceive('put')->with('foo.txt', 'foo bar')->once();
        $generator = new Generator($fileMock);
        $generator->fire();
    }

    public function testGeneratorDoesNotOverwriteFile()
    {
        $fileMock = \Mockery::mock('\stats\jway\File');
        $fileMock->shouldReceive('exists')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(true);

        $fileMock->shouldReceive('put')->never();

        $generator = new Generator($fileMock);
        $generator->fire();
    }
}
```

and here are **File** and **Generator** classes:

**File.php:**

```
class File
{
    public function put($path, $content)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $content);
    }

    public function exists($file_path)
    {
        if (file_exists($file_path)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Generator.php:**

```
class Generator
{
    protected $file;

    public function __construct(File $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    protected function getContent()
    {
        // simplified for demo
        return 'foo bar';
    }

    public function fire()
    {
        $content = $this->getContent();
        $file_path = 'foo.txt';

        if (! $this->file->exists($file_path)) {
            $this->file->put($file_path, $content);
        }
    }

}
```

So, when I run these tests, I get the following message: ***BadMethodCallException: Method ... ::exists() does not exist on this mock object***.

[image]

Comment: try adding `withAnyArgs()` to the mocking of the file as example: `$fileMock->shouldReceive('exists')
            ->once()->withAnyArgs()
            ->andReturn(true);`

Comment: I tried, the same problem still exists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message seems clear to me. You only did setup a expectation for the `put` method, but not `exists`. The `exists` method is called by the class under test in all code paths.

```
public function testGeneratorFire()
{
    $fileMock = \Mockery::mock('\stats\jway\File');
    $fileMock->shouldReceive('put')->with('foo.txt', 'foo bar')->once();

    //Add the line below
    $fileMock->shouldReceive('exists')->once()->andReturn(false);

    $generator = new Generator($fileMock);
    $generator->fire();
}
```

Comment: One question: when we create a Mock object like this: `$fileMock = \Mockery::mock('\stats\jway\File');`   then all methods in that Mock object will return `NULL` by default, right?. If yes, then why we need to setup `exists` method like you did, it will retun NULL and therefore `put` method will be executed anyway?

Comment: You have to add `shouldIgnoreMissing()` to let the mock object return null when you didn't setup an expectation. In this case it would be better to be strict and return false, because a boolean value is what the interface of `exists` defines. If you rewrite `if (! $this->file->exists($file_path))` to `if ($this->file->exists($file_path) === false))` your unit test will break.

Comment: "You only did setup a expectation for the put method, but not exists. The exists method is called by the class under test in all code paths."  Could you explain this more?  Why do we need to set up test expectations for methods that are called incidentally?

Comment: `shouldIgnoreMissing()` definitely helped me avoid some bottlenecks.